# Confidence intervals for non-parametric statistics

Tags: hypothesis-testing, confidence-interval, nonparametric, prediction-interval, tolerance-interval

I have a positive random variable $X$ (say, price or latency or energy) and I want to be able to say something like

1. I am 95% confident that $P(X<42)>0.9$ (percentile) or $P(X<22)\ge\frac12$ (median)
2. I am 97% confident that $EX<17$ (mean)

If I knew that the distribution is, say, [Exponential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution), I could use the confidence interval for $\lambda$. However, I would rather avoid such assumptions.

It seems that I should be able to use the CLT for the [Empirical distribution function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empirical_distribution_function), so, for $x=42$ I can see that $$\hat{F}_n(42)-F(42)\sim N(0,\frac{F(42)(1-F(42))}n)$$

Am I barking up the wrong tree here?

How do I make the type (1) statement? (2 is optional)

Comment: For #1, do you mean that you're looking for confidence intervals for the 0.5 and 0.9 quantiles?

Comment: (1) Is called a *tolerance interval* (or *tolerance limit*), while (2) indeed is a confidence interval.  Nonparametric TLs are usually based on order statistics.  There's not much in the way of good accounts to be found with a Web search, but the Hahn & Meeker handbook, *Statistical Intervals,* explains this and some US government guidance has some good material, too: see https://nepis.epa.gov/Exe/ZyPURL.cgi?Dockey=P10055GQ.TXT for instance. Good nonparametric CLs for the mean are hard to come by: it helps immensely to restrict the possible distribution as much as possible.

Comment: @Dave: yes, upper bounds thereof

Comment: This can be addressed with a semiparametric model.  See the chapter on ordinal models for continuous Y in [rms](https://hbiostat.org/rms).

Answer (score 0):

What I am looking for turned out to be either a [tolerance interval](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tolerance_interval) or a [prediction interval](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prediction_interval).

Comment: There isn't anything in your formulation of the question to suggest you were looking for a prediction interval.